Boundary conditions for massive spring hanging vertically
I was trying to to find the poistion of the center of mass of a massive spring hanging vertically under the effect of gravity and I tried to model it with a finite number of springs attached vertically and then to study the limit. I used the coordinates $x=y+u(y)$ where the coordinate y(n) denotes the position of the nth mass without gravity and u(y) is the displacement at coordinate y due to gravity acting on the system. I let $k$ be the elastic constant of the small springs and $\delta y=y(n)-y(n-1)=l_0/N$
whereI called $l_0$ the length of the spring at rest. I use $\tau=k\delta y=Kl_0$ (springs are in series and K is the total elastic constant).
I get the following discrete differential equation for the nth mass at equilibrium: (n<N)
$$m_ng=-k(x_{n+1}+x_{n-1}-2x_{n})$$
now I expanded the RHS noting that $x_{n+1}=y_n+u(y_n)+\delta y+u(y_n+\delta y)-u(y_n)$, $x_{n-1}=y_n-\delta y-u(y_n-\delta y)$ and I expandend $u$ to the second order in Taylor series. What I get is, calling $\lambda =m_n/\delta y$ for all n $$-g\lambda/\tau=\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}$$
$$u(y)=-g\lambda y^2/2\tau+By$$ where I imposed u(0)=0 because the top of the spring is attached to the ceiling. Now comes my problem: most sources I looked up use as a second condition for u(y) $\frac{du}{dy}|_{y=l_0}=0$ in order to find B but this troubles me because if I go back to the discrete case I would like to impose that the last mass also be at rest thus I get the following equation (there are no springs below it): $$m_{N}g=-k(x_{N-1}-x_N)$$ and using the same procedure as above I get $$m_Ng=-k(u(l_0-\delta y)-u(l_0)-\delta y)$$ which after expanding becomes
$$\lambda g/\tau=-(\delta y \frac{d^2u}{dy^2}+1+\frac{du}{dy})/\delta y$$ if I set the slope equal to zero I get in the limit as $\delta y $ goes to zero the RHS diverges. What went wrong? Does discretization fail at the boundary? And if it does, how can I come up with the correct boundary condition to impose on the spring?
Thanks in advance to those who will spend time thinking about my question

Put a virtual load $F$ on the last link (or the end of the spring) and work out the equations in order to see how the bottom boundary condition is in general. Then set $F=0$ and check if the solution matches what you have above. The slope of the deflection (strain) is proportional to the applied load at the end.

The starting equation is $$mg(L-y)=T$$ where T is the tension at y and L its the unstretched length:  $$T=(kL)\left(\frac{dx}{dy}-1 \right)$$The first equation is a force balance on the portion of the spring between location y and the bottom of the spring.  The second equation determines the tension as a function of the axial strain at y.
